# Error image slideshow when booting

Tags: startup, macos, bootable-disk

I am booting an imac from a USB drive containing OS X 10.13. I get an infinite slideshow alternating between the following two images, which don't seem to coherently convey anything. I am able to skip the slideshow, but I am having other problems that I think might be more resolvable if I knew what the slideshow was supposed to mean. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it wants you to connect and turn on your track page or mouse.

Comment: The pictures are *intended* to inform you in a language-independent manner that the system is unable to connect to either a keyboard or a mouse. The arrow in the upper drawing is meant to show you how to turn on the power switch for an Apple Magic Keyboard, and the lower photo is meant to display how to turn on the power for Apple's Magic Mouse.

Comment: Thank you Doc G., looks like it was just the mouse not connected. I was actually hoping for something more significant, as I still have other issues now, but at least I can not worry about this message.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure these images are intended to remind you that the computer is trying to connect to a couple of Bluetooth devices, the second of which appears to show the underside of a Magic Mouse. You should be able to remedy this by performing the [NVram reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) upon restarting, except that when the screen lights at the last startup cycle, you'll have to immediately press and hold "Option" to select your USB drive to boot from again. You may also have to initiate [Safe Boot Mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18760) before the NVram reset. These procedures may take a while, especially when booting from a USB drive.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It does look like it was a no mouse message, as opposed to a bluetooth issue; I am at least tentatively assuming this as I did not get the message when booting with a mouse plugged in from the start.